# How can I make chart like sleep analysis at IOS App in flutter?

Tags: flutter, charts

I just tried to make a sleep chart like [image](https://file3.instiz.net/data/cached_img/upload/2018/04/06/0/645a37fbb81c9d0de6a298eae9734da4.jpg).
So I found [Range Column chart](https://www.syncfusion.com/flutter-widgets/flutter-charts/chart-types/range-column-chart) and decided to use it.

But I don't know **how to change Y axis label like the image.**
How to make chart like image in flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `CustomPaint'.
[Here](https://github.com/jja08111/Learning-Flutter/tree/main/Sleep-data-chart) is a sample code.

#### EDIT:

I released [time chart plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/time_chart)

[image]